# Haskell guards on lambda functions?

Tags: haskell, syntax

Is it possible to have guards on lambda functions?

For example:

```
\k
    | k < 0     -> "negative"
    | k == 0    -> "zero"
    | otherwise -> "positive"
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Other answers show how the extensions `LambdaCase` and `MultiWayIf`, introduced since this answer was first written, can solve this. Without them, the nearest direct translation is something a bit like

```
\k -> case () of
       _ | k < 0     -> "negative"
         | k == 0    -> "zero"
         | otherwise -> "positive"
```

Comment: Never thought of using `_` over `()` :D

Comment: You can use it over anything, of course, but `()` is short and probably least confusing.

Comment: You could also consider the `select` function http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Case#Using_functions

Answer (score 53):

As of [GHC 7.6.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/release-7-6-1.html) there is an extension called `MultiWayIf` that lets you write the following:

```
\k -> if
  | k < 0     -> "negative"
  | k == 0    -> "zero"
  | otherwise -> "positive"
```

Which at the very least is more pleasant to look at than the alternative using `case`.

For pattern-matching, there is a related extension called `LambdaCase`:

```
\case
  "negative" -> -1
  "zero"     -> 0
  "positive" -> 1
  _          -> error "invalid sign"
```

These extensions are not part of standard Haskell, though, and need to be enabled explicitly via a `{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}` or `{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}` pragma at the top of the file, or by compiling with the flag `-XLambdaCase` or `-XMultiWayIf`.

Answer (score 30):

I like to keep lambdas short and sweet so as not to break the reader's visual flow. For a function whose definition is syntactically bulky enough to warrant guards, why not stick it in a `where` clause?

```
showSign k = mysign ++ " (" ++ show k ++ ")"
  where
  mysign
    | k < 0     = "negative"
    | k == 0    = "zero"
    | otherwise = "positive"
```

Answer (score 7):

An elegant and concise way to do it with LambdaCase:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
```

```
\case k | k < 0     -> "negative"
        | k == 0    -> "zero"
        | otherwise -> "positive"
```

or

```
\case
  k | k < 0     -> "negative"
    | k == 0    -> "zero"
    | otherwise -> "positive"
```

A case when I used it, to catch an EOF error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

```
o <- hGetContents e `catch` (\case (e :: IOException) | isEOFError e -> return "")
```

Comment: `Illegal lambda-case (use -XLambdaCase)`

Comment: @mLstudent33 Yeah, that is the expected error if you haven't turned on LambdaCase. You can turn it on with the command line option as the error you pasted suggests, or you can use the pragma shown on the first line of this answer. See the [GHC Users Guide's chapter on Pragmas](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way uses a combination of the `LambdaCase` and `ViewPatterns` GHC extensions:

`{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase, ViewPatterns #-}`

```
\case
    ((< 0) -> True) -> "negative"
    ((==0) -> True) -> "zero"
    _               -> "positive"
```

This keeps you from having to name an intermediate variable.