# Insert one line try-catch block in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, try-catch

I'd like to add a very simple try-catch block with no thrills to an expression in this class instance in order to handle cases where a `Nothing` is returned.

```
instance QWho (Argument -> Predicate -> Predicate) Predicate where
            qWho verb predicate =
                let 
                arg = head (arguments predicate)
                factsByArg = getFactsByArg arg
                in if null factsByArg then error ("The argument <" ++ getValue arg ++ "> does not exist in any fact.") 
                else
                    let locaPreds = filter (\x -> x == (verb (fromJust (getAgentByType x [HUMN])) predicate)) factsByArg
                    in if null locaPreds then error ("No such fact exists.")
                    else
                        let locaArgs = map (\x -> getAgent x) locaPreds
                        in map getValue locaArgs
```

The offending expression is `(\x -> x == (verb (fromJust (getAgentByType x [HUMN])) predicate))`.  This works, except when `fromJust` returns `Nothing`.  Ideally I imagine I could just do something like this:

```
(\x -> try (x == (verb (fromJust (getAgentByType x [HUMN]))))
```

but that doesn't work (it would in a language like Java, though I'd need a catch at the end.)

There are a lot of resources that try to explain how to do a try-catch block in Haskell.  The ones I've found don't offer a single quick fix that I am looking for (i.e. no major restructuring of the code).  Is there a quick fix to ignore the cases where a `Nothing` is returned, rather than have the program quit due to the `Maybe.fromJust` exception?

A relevant source:

(1) http://drunkcoding.tumblr.com/post/692076953/catching-exceptions-in-haskell

Comment: Why don't you check whether `isNothing ...` before using `fromJust`? Or even better, use patter matching and `case` to handle both the `Nothing` and `Just x` cases? The `fromJust` partial function is arguably the worst way to destruct/eliminate a `Maybe a` value. TLDR: don't look for a way to handle the exception, avoid it instead!

Comment: Make sure your `then`/`else`'s are indented farther than their corresponding `if`'s. And the contents of a `let` statement look nicer to me when they're indented farther than the `let`, but that one's just style.

Comment: I'm not certain how to put a case statement in a lambda expression.  See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416475/haskell-guards-on-lambda-functions @genisage Is there a way to just use parens for all the scopes, e.g. like in Lisp?  The editor I use doesn't really work with indentation.

Comment: `case ...` is just an expression, you can put it in a lambda expression just fine, although it *does* create an indentation block inside. Haskell in an editor without indentation sounds painful. However you [*can* use explicit `{;}` instead](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#Explicit_characters_in_place_of_indentation).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `try` and `catch` in Haskell except as `IO` actions, which cannot be used inside pure code. However there *is* a simple quick fix:

```
let locaPreds = filter (\x -> Just x == fmap (\agent -> verb agent predicate)
                                             (getAgentByType x [HUMN]))
                    factsByArg
```

`Maybe` is a member of the `Functor` typeclass, which means it is one of the *many* datatypes for which you can use `fmap` to apply a function to what's "inside" it. So instead of taking things *out* of the `Maybe`, you can push your check *inside* it.

If the result from `getAgentByType x [HUMN]` is `Just agent`, then the function will be applied to `agent`, giving the result `Just (verb agent predicate)`, which you can compare to `Just x`.
If there is a `Nothing`, the result will still be `Nothing`, which is not equal to `Just x`, so the test fails.

The `flip` function allows you to switch the order of arguments of a function, so you could also write that inner lambda expression shorter as `flip verb predicate`.